# Running TurboGears2 in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, turbogears

I would just like to ask if anybody here has run Turbogears2 from an Amazon EC2 instance. I've been looking for a way to do it, but so far searching the Web hasn't given me anything I could use as an example. I did see one here:

http://codersbuffet.blogspot.com/2010/05/announcing-turbpgears-ec2-images.html

Though I think the person used an earlier version of TG in his post.

I thought it would be as simple as changing the host parameter in the development.ini, but that did not work. I've also tried connecting to the instance with the -L option for ssh, but it did not work as well (I did this approach for web2py way back, and it worked).

I'm wondering if I need to configure some file somewhere in the TG2 application. I've also tried searching the TG2 documentation. Either I'm not using the right keywords, or I'm just not getting the right results.

Thanks in advance for any help!

DM

Answer (score 0):

By itself EC2 doesn't provide a platform, you can freely choose a deploy environment from mod_wsgi, circus, gunicorn or whatever your prefer. It's not strictly a TurboGears problem, it can be deployed like any other WSGI application.

There are some tutorial for a step by step deploy on Apache+mod_wsgi and Circus+chausette on the TurboGears documentation, you can find them here: http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/deploy/index.html

Avoid deploying on gearbox+wsgiref because it is not meant for production usage, if you want to use gearbox I suggest you give a try to [waitress](http://pylons.readthedocs.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks! So that's why. Yesterday after sending this message I tried searching again, and I saw some forums discussing about the usage of mod_wsgi. I see.

Anyway, thanks again for the response! :)